# (Hide Video)CSS display: none not working with @media query for iPhone

Tags: css, responsive, ios

I'm trying to use a @media query to hide a video which auto-plays on loop as a landing page. I want to replace the hidden video with a short, full width, responsive .gif background.

Here is a copy of the CSS in use: http://pastie.org/private/dhi4c4dxvysne0r9fkg8g#1

I'm trying to use

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.fullscreen-bg {
background: url('landing.gif') center center / cover no-repeat;
}

.fullscreen-bg__video {
display:none!important;

}
```

I have succeeded in replacing the video with a looping gif, but the large play button still appears on ios devices even though the video itself isn't visible.

Does anyone know of a workaround or fix for this?

EDIT: The large play button is rendered by Safari and apparently you aren't able to hide it. This means that hiding the video will not cut the mustard for responsive-ness.

So how would I go about requesting that the video doesn't load at all with a media query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.video-container {
  background: transparent;
}
.video-container .video {
  display: block;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .video-container {
    background: url('landing.gif') center center / cover no-repeat;
  }
  .video-container .video {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this. I have just implemented a fix for my situation which might also be interesting. I simply used max-device-width instead of max-width and this seemed to override the video with my .gif.